# Django - How to get a response variable from js file?

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, simplejson

I am sending a variable to jquery side from my view. And what i want is taking and using that value in my js file. i tried $.post or response.xx but didn't work. here is my related view part:

```
                try:
                    post = Post(title=title, body=body, isdraft=isdraft, owner=owner)
                    post.save()
                except:
                    post = None
                json_dump = simplejson.dumps(post.id)
                return HttpResponse(json_dump, mimetype='application/json')
```

i can see `post.id` in firebug's response part. but how can i use that value in my js file.what i am trying to do is like:

```
        var auto_save_id = $('#auto_save_id').val();
        if (VALUE_FROM_JSON)){
            auto_save_id = VALUE_FROM_JSON;
        }
```

thank you

edit : here is my all related view part:

```
if 'auto_save_id' in request.POST:
        if request.POST['auto_save_id'] == "0":
            title = request.POST['title']
            body = request.POST['body']
            get_isdraft = request.POST['isdraft']
            if get_isdraft == "True":
                isdraft = True
            else:
                isdraft = False
            owner = request.user
            if request.is_ajax():
                try:
                    post = Post(title=title, body=body, isdraft=isdraft, owner=owner)
                    post.save()
                except:
                    post = None
                json_dump = simplejson.dumps(post.id)
            return HttpResponse(json_dump, mimetype='application/json')
        else:

            post_id = request.POST['auto_save_id']
            title = request.POST['title']
            body = request.POST['body']
            get_isdraft = request.POST['isdraft']
            if get_isdraft == "True":
                isdraft = True
            else:
                isdraft = False
            owner = request.user
            post = Post.objects.get(id=eval(post_id))
            if request.is_ajax():
                post.title = title
                post.body = body
                post.isdraft = isdraft
                post.owner = owner
                post.save()
                json_dump = simplejson.dumps(post.id)
            return HttpResponse(json_dump, mimetype='application/json')
```

i have a hidden input which value is "0". on first load of page that value is "0" 10 secs later auto_save function runs and send data to view. in view , i check if the auto_save_id = 0: if it is , i create new post and send that post's id to template side. after that on every 10 secs ajax must UPDATE that post. to prevent create new post on each 10 secs, i need saved post's id.

i hope this is clear.

Comment: What does `i tried $.post or response.xx but didn't work` mean?

Comment: i tried $.post('json_dump') (also without '') and response.json_dump to get that value from js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you want to send a dictionary to `simplejson.dumps()` like:

```
json_dump = simplejson.dumps({'pid': post.id})
```

Then, in your javascript function, you would get the id with your argument.pid like:

```
function myCallback(data){
    alert(data.pid);
}
```